# Unable to locate file when trying to use a custom php script for enterprise distribution

Tags: php, ios, file

I am currently using apples enterprise distribution method to allow some users to download certain apps to their iOS devices. In the past I've had users who have stolen the .ipa file by just getting to my .plist file. I created a code sample to serve the plist to the user without showing its contents. Like so

```
<?php //Sorry for ugly code, hope this is better
$uhs    = $_GET;
$eccu   = $uhs[base64_decode("id")];
$orr3   = base64_decode("tool");
$os4    = @file_get_contents($orr3 . $eccu);
$oxCrap = $os4;
$k      = $_SERVER;
$ua     = $k[base64_decode("HTTP_USER_AGENT")];
if ($orr3 != base64_decode("tool")) {
echo base64_decode("kys");
}
$ox1233 = false;
if (strpos($ua, base64_decode("itunesstored")) !== false) {
$ox1233 = true;
}
if ($ox1233) {
    echo $oxCrap;
} else {
echo base64_decode("File Guard");
}
?>
```

But right now I have this php file outside a tool directory which has my plist files. What I'm going for is a link like so
itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=https://example.com/test/pshield.php?id=MYFILE.plist

but if the user goes to the MYFILE.plist it will just show  denied access.

But the problem is the link is not going through or it just can't access the file. Am I serving the file wrong in the php code? Please let me know if I need to be more clear.

Comment: And what purpose should all that effort serve?

Comment: So `file_get_contents` retrieves the file given in the `id` GET argument? Your code is very hard to read so I'm just guessing. But you are suppressing the errors from `file_get_contents` and thereby making debugging much harder.

Answer (score 0):

Usually you want the `tool` folder outside of the public www folder. And your `base64_decode` calls seem to be misplaced. I think you wanted to say this:

```
$eccu   = base64_decode($uhs["id"]);
$os4    = @file_get_contents("../tool/" . $eccu);
```

Note the folder separators. Since the file is outside of the public folder, the user doesn't have a way of directly accessing it.